# extending PixiJS class to create multiple sprites with different textures

Tags: javascript, gsap, pixi.js

I'd like to revise this PixiJS example codepen to use multiple textures.
https://codepen.io/ripmurdock/pen/wvQGjoW?editors=0011

The AwesomeSprite class extends PIXI.Sprite.  I expected that each sprite created with this class would use the texture that is passed at the time the class is called.

When the class is called multiple times to create multiple instances with different texture parameters, every instance uses the first texture passed.

I've tried creating multiple classes with unique class names.  Even if the classes are duplicated, PIXI.Sprite creates a new sprite with the first texture that is passed.

How can I revise this code, so that PIXI.Sprite creates a new sprite with the current texture parameter each time the AwesomeSprite class is called?

Thanks!

```
gsap.config({trialWarn: false})
console.clear();

asyncCall();

async function asyncCall() {
let minX = 0;
let minY = 0;
let maxX = window.innerWidth;
let maxY = window.innerHeight;

let total   = 0;
let batch   = 3;
let limit   = 5000;

let ease  = Power0.easeNone;  

const app = new PIXI.Application({autoResize: true, backgroundAlpha: 0});

app.renderer.resize(maxX, maxY);

PIXI.Assets.addBundle('texturesBundle', {
    bunny: 'https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/bunny.png',
    eggHead: 'https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/eggHead.png',
    flowerTop: 'https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/flowerTop.png', 
  });

const assets = await PIXI.Assets.loadBundle('texturesBundle');

let sprites = [];

document.body.appendChild(app.view);  

let container = new PIXI.ParticleContainer(limit, {
  scale: true,
  position: true,
  rotation: true,
  uvs: false,
  alpha: true
});


app.stage.addChild(container);

//
// AwesomeSprite
// ========================================================================
class AwesomeSprite extends PIXI.Sprite {
  constructor(texture) {
    super(texture);       
    let repeat = -1;
    let yoyo = true;
    let time1  = Math.random()*(3-0.5)+0.5
    let time2  = Math.random()*(4.5-2)+2
    let time3  = Math.random()*(4.5-2)+2
    let prog1  = Math.random()
    let prog2  = Math.random()
    let prog3  = Math.random()
    let scale  = Math.random()*0.5
    let alpha  = 1
    let speedX = (Math.random()*(10+10)-10) * (-1 + Math.round(Math.random()) * 2) 
    let speedY = (Math.random()*(10-2)+2) * (-1 + Math.round(Math.random()) * 2)   
    let startX = .5*(maxX)
    let startY = .5*(maxY)
    let angle  = (-1 + Math.round(Math.random()) * 2) * Math.PI * 2

    this.anchor.set(0.5);
    this.pivot.set(0.5);
    this.scale.set(0.1);
    
    this.x = startX;
    this.y = startY; 
    this.alpha = alpha;               
    this.rotation = 0;    
    
    this.speed = new PIXI.Point(speedX, speedY);
        
    gsap.to(this,{ repeat, ease, rotation: angle, duration: time1, }).progress(prog1);    
    gsap.to(this.scale,{ repeat, ease, yoyo, x: 1, y: 1, duration: time3, }).progress(prog3);   
  }
  
  update() {
    
    this.x += this.speed.x;
    this.y += this.speed.y;

    if (this.x > maxX) {
      
      this.x = maxX;
      this.speed.x *= -1;
      
    } else if (this.x < minX) {
      
      this.x = minX;
      this.speed.x *= -1;
    }
    
    if (this.y > maxY) {
      
      this.y = maxY;
      this.speed.y *= -1;
      
    } else if (this.y < minY) {
      
      this.y = minY;
      //this.speed.y = 0;
      //this.speed.y = 0;
      this.speed.y *= -1;
    }
  }
}

    gsap.ticker.add(render);
    createSprites(batch);
    let sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(assets.bunny);
    sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
    sprite.x = app.screen.width * 2/9;
    sprite.y = app.screen.height / 2;
    app.stage.addChild(sprite);
  
    sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(assets.eggHead);
    sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
    sprite.x = app.screen.width * 4/9;
    sprite.y = app.screen.height / 2;
    app.stage.addChild(sprite);
  
    sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(assets.flowerTop);
    sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
    sprite.x = app.screen.width * 6/9;
    sprite.y = app.screen.height / 2;
    app.stage.addChild(sprite);
  
//
// CREATE sprites
// ========================================================================
function createSprites(count) {
  //console.log(count)
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {    
   createSprite(i)
  } 
  
  function createSprite(i) {
    let sprite0
    switch(i%3) {
      case 0:
        sprite0 = new AwesomeSprite(assets.eggHead);
        break;
      case 1:
        sprite0 = new AwesomeSprite(assets.bunny);
        break;
      default:
        sprite0 = new AwesomeSprite(assets.flowerTop);
    }
        
    sprites.push(sprite0);
    container.addChild(sprite0);
    total++
  }
}

//
// RENDER
// ========================================================================
function render() {

  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    sprites[i].update();
  }
  
  app.renderer.render(app.stage);
}
}
```